# How to use Automapper to project into new list

Tags: automapper

I cannot find an example of how to do this.  I am new to AutoMapper.  I may have used the terminology incorrectly.

```
public class Pet
{
    public int petID {get;set;}
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Breed { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public List<Pet> Pets { get; set; }
}


public personVM
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    List <PetDisplay> PetDisplay {get;set}

}


public PetDisplay
{
    int petID {get;set;}
    string petDetails {get;set}  // This should be a string like Pet.Name & " | " & Pet.Breed
}
```

how do map from person to personVM?  Thanks

Comment: i can't see any reference to Automapper. What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: Hi I am getting person from the entityframework so I want to convert person  to personVM.  Person.Pets is a list of Pet objects but in personVM PetDisplay is a list of petDisplay objects..  So when I map from person to personVM I want to transform the list of pets to a list of perDisplay...

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up a mapping from `Person` → `personVM` and from `Pet` → `PetDisplay`:

```csharp
Mapper.CreateMap<Person, personVM>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.PetDisplay, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Pets));

Mapper.CreateMap<Pet, PetDisplay>()
    .ForMember(
        dest => dest.petDetails,
        opt => opt.MapFrom(src => string.Format("{0} | {1}", src.Name, src.Breed)));
```

Example usage:

```csharp
var person = new Person
{
    FirstName = "Jon",
    LastName = "Skeet",
    Pets = new List<Pet>
    {
        new Pet { Breed = "Lab", Name = "Fido" }
    }
};

personVM vm = Mapper.Map<personVM>(person);
```

**Example:** https://dotnetfiddle.net/eL8VyL

PS: I would recommend following the .NET framework naming guidelines and use PascalCase for class and member names (`PersonVM` instead of `personVM`).

Comment: Andrew, your example worked and i got pass that part. Thank you very much for the help and the tip on the PascalCase.  I already do that but i just hacked out what i posted to you guys in notepad in frustration.  Thanks again, keep your phone on i am probably going to need you again.